# Entity framework custom property databinding error

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have an entity generated from a table with an integer property *hide*. I have created a custom property in a partial class, *HideBoolean*, to convert the integer property to a boolean.

```
    Public Property HideBoolean As Boolean
        Get
            Return If(hide = 1, True, False)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.hide = If(value, 1, 0)
        End Set
    End Property
```

I am using an entity data source hooked up to the entity to databind to a formview, the boolean property is databound to a checkbox. On updating the record on the formview I get the following error message

> A property named 'HideBoolean' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or >delete operation. Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are >available to the data source.

I have put some logging on the setter and this is not being hit on the update.

To test the entity I have tried changing the value of the boolean property for a record in code and saving the record and this works.

```
        Dim a As New Data.PortalEntities
        Dim r As Data.Reports_Reports = a.Reports_Reports.Where(Function(b) b.reportID = reportID).FirstOrDefault
        r.HideBoolean = Not r.HideBoolean
        a.SaveChanges()
```

The value is successfully changed in the table.

Edit: this is the code from my aspx

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=PortalEntities" DefaultContainerName="PortalEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Reports_Reports" AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="311" Name="reportID" Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="reportID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DefaultMode="Edit">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        HideBoolean:
        <asp:CheckBox ID="HideBooleanCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("HideBoolean") %>' />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: When you say you have changed the boolean property in code and that works, do you man you just changed the name of the boolean HideBoolean to something else.  Maybe you just need to clean and rebuild?

Comment: @Xaisoft Sorry I mean I have tried changing the value of the property for a record and saved the record, I'll add the code to the question.

Comment: Ok, so if manually setting HideBoolean causes the record to save,  is HideBoolean actually being set?

Comment: Yes, when using the code the setter on HideBoolean is being called.

Comment: But in your post, you said the setter is not being hit on the update.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being very clear, the problem is that the setter is not being called when editing using the databound formview. To test the entity I've tried replicating the process in code and the setter is called and the update works.

Comment: Do you have code for an event when you edit the form. If so, can you post it?

Comment: I have no event handlers on either the formview or the data source. In previous testing I found that the error was being generated after the updating event on the formview but before the updating event on the datasource. I've just replicated the error on a new page with just the datasource, formview and nothing in the code behind.

Comment: @Xaisoft, I think you're off on the wrong track. Tieran I'd suspect the 'Entity Data Source' you mention. You're using a very odd stack of old, new and barely used MS tech, VB (old + never used) with the entity framework (new) using page view ASP.Net (old) and two-way databinding (no-one uses) with an entity datasource (new but no-one uses). I suspect you're hitting a limitation on how the entity databinder does its reflection. Post your asp.net code as well.

Comment: @mattmanser This may be a symptom of being completely self taught and being the only .NET developer in my team! I'm tied to VB and I really like some aspects of the entity framework, what do people use for data input? I've added the code.